# About URLs using REWRITE in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a PHP file and I don't know how to rewrite its URL when 'Borrow Book' link is clicked. In the url, I want the names of the input fields to be posted, not its input values. I have here some some sample links (I can't post image) so it can be better understood:

```
http://localhost/library/borrowedform.php?name=The%20tail%20of%20Lam-ang
```

Here are some the input fields with names:

```
>       <td>Date Borrowed</td>
>       <td><input type="text" id="date" name="**date_borrow**"></td>
>       <tr>
>       <td>Date Will Return</td>
>       <td><input type="date" name="**date_will_return**"></td>
>       <tr>
>       <td>Book Title</td>
>       <td><input type="text" name="**book_title**"></td>
>       <tr>
>       <td>No. Copies</td>
>       <td><input type="text" name="**no_copies**"></td>
```

What I want is this. I have it from Facebook. It's just so amazing that the values are not found in the URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account&section=**username**&view
```

Comment: Hi there you can do it via jquery, just pick the name of input fields and frame your url and then hit an ajax request with post method and then after saving the post values in the session or db redirect to the same url on success and confirm your values by checking the arguments and the previously fetched post values.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna try it. Thanks..

Comment: Not sure if I understood your requirements clearly. Can you try again with some examples.

Comment: sample this is my current url: http://localhost/library/borrowedform.php?name=css%20design what i want is http://localhost/library/borrowedform.php?name=book_title

Comment: @Cecil - the one that you mention is still the same right? what is the difference between the two that you have mentioned in the comment here?

Comment: @MihirChhatre: no difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have clean URL's you can definitely use .htaccess files for rewriting how the variables are formed in the URL.

Your current URL is: localhost/library/borrowedform.php?name=css%20design

You can achieve a clean URL like: localhost/library/css%20design/ using .htaccess files.

This is a good article to start reading about htaccess -

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score -1):

You should not use a name different from ID, you should not use a id at all.

For what you want to do, transmit known data, use hidden field

```
<input name="date-borrowed" type="hidden" value="the date">
```

This kind of field can be tweeked by users, so you cannot rely on them and you must check them on serverside.

Comment: "You should not use a name at all". Wrong. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.2

Comment: In short, the *name is the identifier that is sent to the server* when you submit the form. The id is a *unique identifier for the browser*, clientside, for javascript and such.

Comment: ID's are still useful for JavaScript to access. Inputs should have a name, but optionally can have an id if your JS is going to access it :-)